# Disable Tooltip Gradient

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I would like to pass multiple parameters to the `Tooltip`, and I wrote the following code as a placeholder. However, my `Tooltip` background color does not uniform, there is gradient. How could I disable ?

```
chart.options.tooltip.template = "Name : AnyName<br>
  First Value: Any Value 1 <br>
  Second Value: Any Value 2";
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: @ezanker, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvn7kvt2/ , however this shade effect does not come into the picture on fiddle. It comes on my actual implementation.

Comment: in your application, what theme are you using? The tooltip has the CSS classes k-tooltip and k-chart-tooltip. Can you see if your CSS is applying the gradient? You could also try setting the series.overlay: { gradient: "none" }: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.overlay.gradient

Comment: I have also added my css, it is almost same with my actual implementation. However, still I could not able to reproduce same problem in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rvn7kvt2/1/

Comment: I have also tried  `series.overlay: { gradient: "none" }` but problem still remains same.

Comment: Inspect the tooltip in the chrome dev tools and see where the gradient is specified, then override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe k-chart-tooltip is specifying a background-image:

Try adding a CSS rule:

```
.k-chart-tooltip {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried, http://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-tooltip-gradients- but no luck.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, inspect the tooltip in chrome dev tools and see if another CSS rule is overriding this one.

Comment: How could inspect the tooltip, it appear and disappear. Is there a trick to follow? I have upvoted your effort.

Comment: @mystackoverflow, open the dev tools and dock them to the bottom of the window. Then when you right-click a tooltip, if the inspect element option in the context menu is over the dev tools, it won't disappear.